# How to use StringFormat via binding in a DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, string-formatting

I'd like to present my data in a DataGrid using StringFormat. The objects have a property with the formatstring I'd like to use... for example "{0:0.##} mmol/l" or "{0:0.##} mg/dl" to display the results in varying units.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource stringFormatConverter}}" />
```

The converter in C#:

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:0.##} mmol/l", value);
    }
    [...]
}
```

How can I tell the converter to use a formatstring which is a property of the item I am binding to instead of the one in the current version of the converter?

**Edit**:
results is an ObservableCollection of Result which looks like

```
public class Result
{
  public double Value {get; set; }
  public string Key {get; set; }
  public string FormatString {get; set; }
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Which object has the property with the formatstring? If results is IEnumerable<X>, then what is X and what properties does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the entire object to the converter rather than its `Value` property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource stringFormatConverter}}" />
```

Then, you can change the converter to format the string according to the given object:

```cs
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = (Result)value;
        return string.Format(result.FormatString, result.Value);
    }
}
```

Another possible solution would be to have the `Result` class expose another property which will return the formatted value, then bind against `FormattedValue` (with no converter):

```cs
public class Result
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string FormatString { get; set; }

    public string FormattedValue
    {
        get { return string.Format(FormatString, Value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion couldn't work... the value couldn't be casted to Result because it was of type double. I already hat the second suggestion in mind but was looking for some nifty converter solution, but sometimes 'Keep it simple' is still the best way ;) Thank you!

Comment: Note that in the first solution you should change your binding, i.e. don't bind to `Value` but to the datacontext. Have a closer look - that solution should work.